# How does one embed a simple table into hangout Chat

Tags: google-hangouts

One can create formatted text using Cards for a chat bot. 
I need a way to have a formatted table inside the Cards.
What should the json look like for a simple 3 columns and 3 rows table.
Sections are dividing cards vertically , How does one divide the card horizontally for a small formatted table to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

As of now Hangouts Chat currently does not have this feature. The best way to have this pushed to Hangouts Chat is probably by filing feedback via https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=350158&template=1047215 and hope that it gets enough upvotes.